# Shopware: Page object is null

Tags: php, twig, shopware

I created a new plugin, with a simple custom frontend route. The `page` object is null when printed, so the elements inside are gone. I know I can just pass it from the `renderStorefront` function as a second parameter, but don't know what to fill in it because usually it is filled automatically.

The controller php file `customStatusController.php`:

```
/**
 * @Route("/custom-status", name="frontend.store.customplugin.custom-status", options={"seo"="false"}, methods={"GET"})
 */
public function index(): Response
    return $this->renderStorefront('@Storefront/storefront/index.html.twig');
}
```

The view twig file `index.html.twig`:

```
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/page/content/index.html.twig' %}

{% block base_header_flyout %}
    {{ dump(page) }}
{% endblock %}
```

How can I pass/inherit the `page` object that comes from the cms with all the child objects?

Answer (score 2):

You need to inject the`Shopware\Storefront\Page\GenericPageLoader` and then create a `NavigationPage` from it.

So something like should do the trick ( did not test it it ):

```
<?php

    /**
     * @var GenericPageLoader
     */
    private $genericPageLoader;

    ....

    public function __construct(GenericPageLoader $genericPageLoader)
    {
        $this->genericPageLoader = $genericPageLoader;
    }

    /**
    * @Route("/custom-status", name="frontend.store.customplugin.custom-status", options={"seo"="false"}, methods={"GET"})
    */
    public function index(Request $request, SalesChannelContext $context): Response

        $page = $this->genericPageLoader->load($request, $context);
        $page = NavigationPage::createFrom($page);

        return $this->renderStorefront('@Storefront/storefront/index.html.twig', 
        [
            'page' => $page,
        ]);
    }
```

Then you should have at least the `HeaderPagelet`, `FooterPagelet` etc. within the `$page` variable.

You can also take a look at our Blog Plugin how we created the [detail page with a custom Controller](https://github.com/ChristopherDosin/Shopware-6-Blog-Plugin/blob/master/src/Controller/BlogController.php#L52).

However: You also should ask yourself if a custom Controller is really needed, or if a CmsDataResolver / CMS Element would do the trick also which is way more flexible.

Comment: I got an empty header and footer when I tried to load the page using genericPageLoader, I have used it in /checkout/offcanvas route